# R function to spread rows into columns

Tags: r

Spread row values into columns

Data looks like

```
> head(df2)
    ID fungi     Conc   Abs date_no
1    1    R3 2.500000 0.209       0
22   1    R3 1.250000 0.153       0
43   1    R3 0.625000 0.159       0
64   1    R3 0.312500 0.164       0
85   1    R3 0.156250 0.157       0
106  1    R3 0.078125 0.170       0
```

And I used this function, which spread the date column into three columns but didn't populate them correctly.

```
separate_DF <- spread(df2, "date_no", "Abs")
```

What I get is this...

```
> head(df3)
  ID fungi       Conc date_no_0 date_no_1 date_no_3
1  1    R3 0.01953125     0.162        NA        NA
2  1    R3 0.03906253     0.169        NA        NA
3  1    R3 0.07812500     0.170        NA        NA
4  1    R3 0.15625000     0.157        NA        NA
5  1    R3 0.31250000     0.164        NA        NA
6  1    R3 0.62500000     0.159        NA        NA
```

So that the three date columns are populated by the Abs values. And each fungi at each concentration is its own row.

Comment: What's wrong with what you get from your spread call? Looks fine to me. You could add `sep="_"` to the argument list to get the `date` into your col names

Comment: It does some weird calculations with concentration, so the column is no longer correct. When it separates Abs values across the three new date columns, only one column is populated at a time. So date1 has values 1:24, date2 25:96, and date3 97:168. When one column has values, the other two have NAs. Adding sep="_" did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you give some sample data where that problem happens? Because it doesn't happen with what you provided. Note that spread will create a row for every unique fungi/conc combination, and show all the dates for that unique combination.

Comment: Updated original post with more information. Is that helpful?

Comment: When I run the code in your question or in TheRimalaya's answer on the new data in your question, I get a result that looks perfectly reasonable. Perhaps you could do the same, put the result in your question, and not exactly what seems wrong to you.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Try `spread(date_df[,c(1:2,4:5)],date_no,Abs,sep="Abs") %>% left_join(., spread(date_df[,c(1:3,5)],date_no,Conc,sep="Conc"),by="fungi")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

```
library(tidyr)

txt <- "fungi date  Abs Conc
1      1     x   2.5
1      2     x   2.5
1      3     x   2.5
2      1     x   2.5
2      2     x   2.5
2      3     x   2.5
"
date_df <- read.table(textConnection(txt), header = TRUE)
print(spread(date_df, date, Abs, sep=""))
```

Result:

```
  fungi Conc date1 date2 date3
1     1  2.5     x     x     x
2     2  2.5     x     x     x
```